# how to get all related model IDs in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

Suppose $model hase some items (one to many relationship), So in Yii $model->items returns an array of item models. 
 How can I get an array of IDs of related items. This means each element of returned array is an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply write your own function for this, e.g.

```
public function getItemsIDs()
{
  $ids = array();
  foreach($this->items as $item)
    $ids[] = $item->id;
  return $ids;
}
```

After you just have to call `$model->itemsIDs`.

EDIT : as *darkheir* said in its comment, you should consider using [DAO](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao).

Comment: This solution is fine, except when we need to improve performances, because it will load the related items in one query, create the related objects and then perform the `foreach` loop to get only the ids. This is why perform a DAO query might be better if performance are something important in the webapp.

Comment: Thanks men, for sure direct query has better performance. Now I know there is no special Yii function for my question!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of direct query, run from Model:

```
$this->getDbConnection()->createCommand("SELECT id FROM items WHERE model_id = :modelId")->bindParam(":modelId", $model->id, PDO::PARAM_STR)->queryColumn();
```

In result you will get numeric Array() with IDs from the table as values.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant.

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT id FROM items WHERE model_id=".$model->id)->queryColumn()
```

This will get all IDs from table as array